# Get Friday and Saturday's Data on Monday

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a query where on Monday it gives me the data from Friday and Saturday. On Tuesday through Friday it gives me the data from yesterday. Here is my query so far:

````
[MVMT_NUMBER],
CAST(RIGHT([MVMT_NUMBER], PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', REVERSE([MVMT_NUMBER])+' ')) as INT) as movement,
[MVMT_TYPE], 
[OPERATOR],
[EQUIPMENT],
[ORIG],
[DEST],
[MVMT_STATUS],

CASE WHEN  [GROSS_WEIGHT_(KG)] < 0 THEN 0 ELSE [GROSS_WEIGHT_(KG)] END AS [GROSS_WEIGHT_(KG)],
CASE WHEN [NET_WEIGHT_(KG)]< 0 THEN 0 ELSE [NET_WEIGHT_(KG)] END AS [NET_WEIGHT_(KG)],
CASE WHEN [NMBR_ULDS] < 0 THEN 0 ELSE [NMBR_ULDS] END AS [NMBR_ULDS],
CASE WHEN [NMBR_POS] < 0 THEN 0 ELSE [NMBR_POS] END AS [NMBR_POS]

FROM SERVER
WHERE [F-T-O] = 'T'
  AND DEST IN ('CVG', 'CVG CRN', 'MIA', 'MIA GTW', 'LAX', 'LAX GTW', 'JFK', 'JFK GTW', 'ORD', 'ORD GTW')
  AND [MVMT_NUMBER] LIKE 'X%'
  AND [MVMT_NUMBER] NOT LIKE '%a%' 
  AND MVMT_DT = CONVERT(date, getdate()-1)```
````

Comment: So where are you stuck? What are you asking for help with? And how about providing some sample data and desired results.

Comment: When GETDATE() returns a monday date, you need to subtract 3 days, not one. That is relatively simply logic, but have you considered holidays and other non-work days? The best approach is to create a calendar table - you can find many suggestions by searching on that term.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @today date = GETDATE();

DECLARE @start date = DATEADD(DAY, 
  CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @today) = N'Monday' 
    THEN -3 ELSE -1 END, @today);

SELECT ...
WHERE ...
AND MVMT_DT >= @start
AND MVMT_DT <  @today;
```

Don't use `getdate()-1`, it's a [lazy shortcut with hidden technical debt](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations).